# Как подсчитать количество элементов массива?

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть массив:

```
int[] array1 = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
```

Как подсчитать количество элементов, вывести должно 5.
На PHP аналог - `array_sum()`

И ещё!

Как вот этот массив вывести так:

> `1
>   1
>   1
>   0
>   0`

т.е. отсортировать, и вывести сначала 1-цы, а потом нули...

Answer (score 2):

кол-во элементов:

```
array1.Length;
```

Сортировка:

```
array1.OrderByDescending(num=>num);
```

вывод:

```
foreach(var n in array1.OrderByDescending(num=>num))
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

Comment: у меня не найдено такого метода, можете полностью код показать?

Comment: я пишу такие вещи в LINQPad`е, и это и есть "код колностью".
Попробуйте добавить ``using System.Linq;``

Comment: Вот такое написал, не работает

    int[] array1 = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
    int[] mex = Array.Sort(array1);
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++){
        Console.WriteLine(mex[i]);
    }

ругается на Array.

Comment: Array.Sort() ничего не возвращает, он сортирует массив, кот. вы передали в качестве параметра.

Comment: а как тогда написать?
for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++){
    Console.WriteLine(Array.Sort(array1[i]));
   }

Comment: Примерно так:  

    array1.sort();
    for (int i = array1.Length-1; i >= 0; i--){ Console.WriteLine(array1[i]); } // в обратном порядке, т.к. тебе сначала 1 нужны

Comment: ну что за вопросы? на данном ресурсе не выполняют заданий за вас!

    int[] array1 = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 };
    Array.Sort(array1);
    for (int i = array1.Length-1; i >=0 ; i--)
        Console.WriteLine(array1[i]);

Comment: Походу дела нужно ещё и с нового ряда ))

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду сумму элементов массива (аналог `array_sum`), то это очень легко делается в LINQ

```
int total = array1.Sum();
```

Про вывод уже написали.